# connecting two SIP phones from different LANs over ZeroTier openwrt

Tags: routing, asterisk, voip, openwrt

i make site to site conncetion by tp-link n600 openwrt zerotier and no problem , i can reach every thing in two sites and ping ok
but i have in site 1 Issable and in site 2 sip phone

```
--------------------------+---------------------------------     
openwrt zerotier 1        I     openwrt zerotier 2 
192.168.193.2            I           192.168.193.3
--------------------------+---------------------------------
--------------------------+---------------------------------     
LAN 1                     I           LAN 2
192.168.2.0/24            I           192.168.3.0/24
--------------------------+---------------------------------
                          I                          
  Issabel              I                                         
192.168.2.100             I           
      ^                   I                 ^
      |                   I                 |
      v                   I                 v                                   
SIP phone 1               I           SIP phone 2                                        
192.168.2.101             I           192.168.3.101
```

No problem to see phone on LAN 1. The problem is how to see phone on LAN 2 Although I can ping it from Lan 1
and in Lan 2 I can Ping and enter to Issable in Lan2

when enter sip account in sip phone 2 give this massage in asterisk sip debug

Retransmitting #4 (NAT) to 192.168.2.1:38182:
OPTIONS sip:102@192.168.3.187:38182 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.100:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1d486566;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "Unknown" sip:Unknown@192.168.2.100;tag=as452a4afc
To: sip:102@192.168.3.101:38182
Contact: sip:Unknown@192.168.2.100:5060
Call-ID: 4fa209177da542cc3ea8958e411301de@192.168.2.00:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: IPBX-2.11.0.49(16.21.1)
Date: Fri, 02 Sep 2022 23:06:11 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0

Can anybody help please?